# GDAL - Warp image to inverted y-axis coordinate system (Apple MapKit) gives image upside down

Tags: ios, geospatial, gdal, geo

I'm having an image of a map that I want to geo reference and overlay on the built-in map on iOS. I'm using GDAL programmatically.

**Step 1 (OK) - Geo referencing (works fine)**

Currently I'm calculating a GeoTransform (the 6 coefficients) from three ground control points to geo reference the image and it gives me the correct 6 coefficients.

**Step 2 (PROBLEM) - Warp image + get GeoTransform for new transformed image**

The image becomes upside down! This is because the target coordinate system (Apple's own coordinate system in MapKit) has inverted y-axis which increases as you go south.

**Question**

How can I get GDAL to warp the image correctly (and at the same time give me a correct GeoTransform to go with it)?

**What I've tried**

I changed value 5/6 in the original GeoTransform before warping. This gives a correct warp of the image, but the new GeoTransform is wrong.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
- (WarpResultC*)warpImageWithGeoTransform:(NSArray<NSNumber*>*)geoTransformArray sourceFile:(NSString*)inFilepath destinationFile:(NSString*)outFilepath
{
    GDALAllRegister();

    GDALDriverH hDriver;
    GDALDataType eDT;
    GDALDatasetH hDstDS;
    GDALDatasetH hSrcDS;

    // Open the source file.
    hSrcDS = GDALOpen( inFilepath.UTF8String, GA_ReadOnly );
    CPLAssert( hSrcDS != NULL );

    // Set the GeoTransform on the source image
    // HERE IS WHERE I NEED NEGATIVE VALUES OF 4 & 5 TO GET A PROPER IMAGE
    double geoTransform[] = { geoTransformArray[0].doubleValue, geoTransformArray[1].doubleValue, geoTransformArray[2].doubleValue, geoTransformArray[3].doubleValue, -geoTransformArray[4].doubleValue, -geoTransformArray[5].doubleValue };
    GDALSetGeoTransform(hSrcDS, geoTransform);

    // Create output with same datatype as first input band.
    eDT = GDALGetRasterDataType(GDALGetRasterBand(hSrcDS, 1));

    // Get output driver (GeoTIFF format)
    hDriver = GDALGetDriverByName( "GTiff" );
    CPLAssert( hDriver != NULL );

    // Create a transformer that maps from source pixel/line coordinates
    // to destination georeferenced coordinates (not destination
    // pixel line).  We do that by omitting the destination dataset
    // handle (setting it to NULL).
    void *hTransformArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer( hSrcDS, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, 1 );
    CPLAssert( hTransformArg != NULL );

    // Get approximate output georeferenced bounds and resolution for file.
    double adfDstGeoTransform[6];
    int nPixels=0, nLines=0;
    CPLErr eErr = GDALSuggestedWarpOutput( hSrcDS, GDALGenImgProjTransform, hTransformArg, adfDstGeoTransform, &nPixels, &nLines );
    CPLAssert( eErr == CE_None );
    GDALDestroyGenImgProjTransformer( hTransformArg );

    // Create the output file.
    hDstDS = GDALCreate( hDriver, outFilepath.UTF8String, nPixels, nLines, 4, eDT, NULL );
    CPLAssert( hDstDS != NULL );

    // Write out the projection definition.
    GDALSetGeoTransform( hDstDS, adfDstGeoTransform );

    // Copy the color table, if required.
    GDALColorTableH hCT = GDALGetRasterColorTable( GDALGetRasterBand(hSrcDS, 1) );
    if( hCT != NULL )
        GDALSetRasterColorTable( GDALGetRasterBand(hDstDS, 1), hCT );

    // Setup warp options.
    GDALWarpOptions *psWarpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();
    psWarpOptions->hSrcDS = hSrcDS;
    psWarpOptions->hDstDS = hDstDS;

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*      Do we have a source alpha band?                                 */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    bool enableSrcAlpha = GDALGetRasterColorInterpretation( GDALGetRasterBand(hSrcDS, GDALGetRasterCount(hSrcDS) )) == GCI_AlphaBand;
    if(enableSrcAlpha) { printf( "Using band %d of source image as alpha.\n", GDALGetRasterCount(hSrcDS) ); }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*      Setup band mapping.                                             */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    if(enableSrcAlpha)
        psWarpOptions->nBandCount = GDALGetRasterCount(hSrcDS) - 1;
    else
        psWarpOptions->nBandCount = GDALGetRasterCount(hSrcDS);

    psWarpOptions->panSrcBands = (int *) CPLMalloc(psWarpOptions->nBandCount*sizeof(int));
    psWarpOptions->panDstBands = (int *) CPLMalloc(psWarpOptions->nBandCount*sizeof(int));

    for( int i = 0; i < psWarpOptions->nBandCount; i++ )
    {
        psWarpOptions->panSrcBands[i] = i+1;
        psWarpOptions->panDstBands[i] = i+1;
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*      Setup alpha bands used if any.                                  */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    if( enableSrcAlpha )
        psWarpOptions->nSrcAlphaBand = GDALGetRasterCount(hSrcDS);

    psWarpOptions->nDstAlphaBand = GDALGetRasterCount(hDstDS);

    psWarpOptions->pfnProgress = GDALTermProgress;

    // Establish reprojection transformer.
    psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer( hSrcDS, NULL, hDstDS, NULL, FALSE, 0.0, 1 );
    psWarpOptions->pfnTransformer = GDALGenImgProjTransform;

    // Initialize and execute the warp operation.
    GDALWarpOperation oOperation;
    oOperation.Initialize( psWarpOptions );
    CPLErr warpError = oOperation.ChunkAndWarpImage( 0, 0, GDALGetRasterXSize( hDstDS ), GDALGetRasterYSize( hDstDS ) );
    CPLAssert( warpError == CE_None );

    GDALDestroyGenImgProjTransformer( psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg );
    GDALDestroyWarpOptions( psWarpOptions );
    GDALClose( hDstDS );
    GDALClose( hSrcDS );

    WarpResultC* warpResultC = [WarpResultC new];
    warpResultC.geoTransformValues = @[@(adfDstGeoTransform[0]), @(adfDstGeoTransform[1]), @(adfDstGeoTransform[2]), @(adfDstGeoTransform[3]), @(adfDstGeoTransform[4]), @(adfDstGeoTransform[5])];
    warpResultC.newX = nPixels;
    warpResultC.newY = nLines;

    return warpResultC;
}
```

Comment: Check [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114978/raster-created-by-python-gdal-interpreted-upside-down) Maybe you can flip the image zi = zi[::-1,:] Or you are missing a minus somewhere like [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24055/raster-data-array-output-flipped-on-x-axis-using-python-gdal)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I can flip the image (see details in the question), but I can't do it and still have a correct geotransform in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using [GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702062214/http://www.gdal.org:80/warptut.html). From documentation:
*Create a transformer that maps from source pixel/line coordinates to destination georeferenced coordinates (not destination pixel line).  We do that by omitting the destination dataset handle (setting it to NULL).*

**Other related info for your task from [gdal_alg.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716151832/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdal__alg_8h.html#a7671696d085085a0bfba3c3df9ffcc0a):**
Create image to image transformer.

This function creates a transformation object that maps from pixel/line coordinates on one image to pixel/line coordinates on another image. The images may potentially be georeferenced in different coordinate systems, and may used GCPs to map between their pixel/line coordinates and georeferenced coordinates (as opposed to the default assumption that their geotransform should be used).

This transformer potentially performs three concatenated transformations.

The first stage is from source image pixel/line coordinates to source image georeferenced coordinates, and may be done using the geotransform, or if not defined using a polynomial model derived from GCPs. If GCPs are used this stage is accomplished using GDALGCPTransform().

The second stage is to change projections from the source coordinate system to the destination coordinate system, assuming they differ. This is accomplished internally using GDALReprojectionTransform().

The third stage is converting from destination image georeferenced coordinates to destination image coordinates. This is done using the destination image geotransform, or if not available, using a polynomial model derived from GCPs. If GCPs are used this stage is accomplished using GDALGCPTransform(). **This stage is skipped if hDstDS is NULL when the transformation is created.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is what I'm doing. I'm using that page you link to as a base. The problem is still that the image is warped to upside down as the georeference coordinate system is upside down.

Comment: Have you tried to set NULL to hDstDS?
hTransformArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer(hSrcDS, pszSrcWKT, **hDstDS**, pszDstWKT, FALSE, 0, 1 );

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't understand if what you are writing could help me. I added some code to the question so you understand what I do today, then it might be easier to explain what you mean? Thanks!